# how to add item in java POS

Tags: java

```
    String item1="Burger";
    String item2="Softdrink";
    int burger_price=40, sofdrink_price=20;
    int x=0;
    while(x==0){
    System.out.println("Select item [1] burger [2] sofdrink");
    int select=scan.nextInt();



    switch(select){
    case 1: 
            System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
            int qty=scan.nextInt();

            int total=qty*burger_price;
            System.out.println("Item: Burger");
            System.out.println("Quanity: "+qty);
            System.out.println("Total: "+total);
            x=1;
        break;
    case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
            int qty2=scan.nextInt();

            int total2=qty2*sofdrink_price;
            System.out.println("Item: Softdrink");
            System.out.println("Quanity: "+qty2);
            System.out.println("Total: "+total2);
            x=1;
        break;
    default: System.out.println("Select [1] and [2] only");
    }
    }//end while`
```

Comment: can anyone help with my java project?

Comment: Add item to what? What are your exceptions? What is the code currently doing? And what should it be doing?

Comment: the code above will ask the user to buy any of the choices(burger and sofdrink) then it will ask for quantity and it will display the total... my question is what if the costumer wanted to by some more of the item? how will i do that and display all the total... thank you so much... any answer is appreciated

Comment: @MadProgrammer the code above will ask the user to buy any of the choices(burger and sofdrink) then it will ask for quantity and it will display the total... my question is what if the costumer wanted to by some more of the item? how will i do that and display all the total... thank you so much... any answer is appreciated

Comment: And that to your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need some kind of loop...

```
boolean done = false;
do {
    //...
} while (!done);
```

Then you need to provide some way for the user to exit the loop

```
boolean done = false;
do {
    System.out.println("Select item [1] burger [2] sofdrink or [0] when you're done");
    //...
    switch(select){
        case 0:
            done = true;
            break;
    }
} while (!done);
```

Now, you need someway to keep a running tally of what's been ordered, since you only have two items, you could use two variables...

```
int burgerCount = 0;
int softDrinkCount = 0;
boolean done = false;
do {
    //...
```

Now you can just increment the counters based on the user selection...

Now, automatically, you need to ask the user for two things, what they want and how much they want, you could simplify the process a bit by been a little clever...

```
System.out.println("Select item [1] burger [2] sofdrink or [0] when you're done");
int select=scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
switch (select) {
    case 0:
        done = true;
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
        int qty=scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        switch (select) {
            case 1:
                burgerCount += qty;
                break;
            case 1:
                softDrinkCount += qty;
                break;
        }
        break;
}
// Show details
```

Make sure, you call `nextLine` after you read the `nextInt`, as there is still a carriage return in the buffer ;)

Then you can display running a tally...

```
    //...
    System.out.println("You've ordered...");
    double burgerTally = burger_price * burgerCount;
    double drinkTally = burger_price * drinkTally;
    System.out.println(burgerCount + " burgers @ $" + burger_price + " for a sub total of $" + burgerTally);
    System.out.println(softDrinkCount + " soft drinks @ $" + sofdrink_price + " for a sub total of $" + drinkTally);
    System.out.println("For a total of $" + (burgerTally + drinkTally));
} while (!done);
```

Because of the way the code is laid out, the tally will be displayed regardless of what you pick...

Now, if you have more items, then an array is going to come in very handy and will reduce the over all amount of code you might need...

Answer (score 0):

MadProgrammer gave a really great explanation. I just put it together as a code. I tried to make minimum changes to your original code so that you understand better.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BugerCheese {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
            int burger_price=40, sofdrink_price=20;
            int qty1=0, qty2=0;
            while(true){
                System.out.println("Select item [1] burger [2] sofdrink");
                int select=scan.nextInt();
                switch(select){
                    case 1: 
                        System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
                        qty1 += scan.nextInt();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("Enter Quantity: ");
                        qty2 += scan.nextInt();
                        break;
                    default: System.out.println("Select [1] and [2] only");
                }
                System.out.println("Enter 9 to add more items. Enter any other key to calculate total");
                if(9!=scan.nextInt()){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(qty1>0){
                int total=qty1*burger_price;
                System.out.println("Item: Burger");
                System.out.println("Quanity: "+qty1);
                System.out.println("Total: "+total);
            }

            if(qty2>0){
                int total2=qty2*sofdrink_price;
                System.out.println("Item: Softdrink");
                System.out.println("Quanity: "+qty2);
                System.out.println("Total: "+total2);   
            }
            System.out.println("GrandTotal: "+(qty1*burger_price+qty2*sofdrink_price));
        }
    }
```